# Ranking Value by input Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to make some form to rank job from what they like and dislike, what I want is when the user input the number on the first `input:number` with number 4, they cannot input the same number on second `input:number`, also I want to limit the input form 1 to 5 only, so I put the min and max on my input:number to prevent user write number more than 5, but it seems only work after submit the form, I want to make it automatically when user input the number.

here is my form

```
<form action="result.php" method="post" id="form"> 
<input required type="number" min="1" max="5" name="11">
<input required type="number" min="1" max="5" name="12">
<input required type="number" min="1" max="5" name="13">
<input required type="number" min="1" max="5" name="14">
<input required type="number" min="1" max="5" name="15">
<button class="button3" name="click" >Submit</button>
```

How can I do that? any suggestion is welcomed, also is it possible to use 2 dimension radio button (never heard of it thought)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add event to on change of input value, and check for value against each input value if its not empty, the following code should work

Note: I have used jQuery for this following example

```js
jQuery('input[type="number"]').change(function(){
 var currentObj = jQuery(this)[0];
  jQuery('#error').empty('');
  if(jQuery(this).val() > 5){
      jQuery('#error').append('<p>number must be not more than 5</p>');
    jQuery(this).val('');
  }
  jQuery('input[type="number"]').each(
    function(i,v){
      if(jQuery(v).val()){
      if(jQuery(v).attr('name') !== currentObj.name){
        if(jQuery(v).val() == currentObj.value){
            jQuery('#error').append('<p>number must ne unique</p>');
            jQuery('input[name="'+currentObj.name+'"').val('');
            console.log(currentObj.name); 
        }
      }
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<div id="error"></div>
<form action="result.php" method="post" id="form"> 
<input required type="number" min="1" max="5" name="11">
<input required type="number" min="1" max="5" name="12">
<input required type="number" min="1" max="5" name="13">
<input required type="number" min="1" max="5" name="14">
<input required type="number" min="1" max="5" name="15">
<button class="button3" name="click" >Submit</button>
```

JSBIN DEMO - https://jsbin.com/gazehik/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks Dude, Bless you, I will try your solution, I will keep you updated

Answer (score 0):

I suggested you to use select/option with JQuery instead:

```
<form id='form1' action="result.php" method="post" id="form"> 
    Job A:<select id='option1' required><option value=''><option value='1'>1<option value='2'>3<option value='3'>3<option value='4'>4<option value='5'>5</select>
    &nbsp;Job B:<select id='option2' required><option value=''><option value='1'>1<option value='2'>3<option value='3'>3<option value='4'>4<option value='5'>5</select>
    &nbsp;Job C<select id='option3' required><option value=''><option value='1'>1<option value='2'>3<option value='3'>3<option value='4'>4<option value='5'>5</select>
    &nbsp;Job D:<select id='option4' required><option value=''><option value='1'>1<option value='2'>3<option value='3'>3<option value='4'>4<option value='5'>5</select>
    &nbsp;Job E:<select id='option5' required><option value=''><option value='1'>1<option value='2'>3<option value='3'>3<option value='4'>4<option value='5'>5</select> 
    <button class="button3" name="click" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and JQuery script as:

```
$("#form1").find("select").each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){ //if any select input is changed
            var changedId = $(this).attr('id'); //store the changed id
            var valSelected = $(this).val(); //store the selected value

            $("#form1").find("select").each(function(){ // loop through form1 again 
                var loopId = $(this).attr('id');
                if(loopId!==changedId){ //every select in put, but selected
                    $(this).find('option').each(function(){ //loop through every option
                        if($(this).val()===valSelected){ // make the selected option disabled
                            $(this).attr('disabled',true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```